# How to integrate this function with $\ln(x)$ in the numerator?

Tags: integration

I have to integrate $$ \iint {\log \sqrt x \over xy} \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy$$ I don't really care about integrating over $y$, I can't begin to integrate over $x$ because I don't know how. What rules do I use to do this, I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It's actually a very simple substitution, because $d(\ln x) = dx/x$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\frac{\log\sqrt x}{xy}dx=\frac1{2y}\int\frac{\log x}xdx=\frac1{4y}\log^2x+C$$